# Several linq queries into on query

Tags: sql, linq, linqpad, query-performance

The below code hits the database 3 times using linq. (using LinqPad for testing)

I can write the statement in t-sql and do the same call with one database hit using a selected within select.

**LINQ (3 database hits)**

```
var cId = "11";

int[] eIds = (
from e in App_events 
where e.cId == cId && e.CategoryID == 3 && e.Active
select e.Id).ToArray();

int[] tIds = (
from t in App_event_tasks where eIds.Contains(t.EventID)
select t.ActionID).ToArray();

var data = (
from tr in App_trackings
where tIds.Contains(tr.ActionID)
select tr).ToList();

data.Dump();
```

---

**SQL (one database hit)**

```
select * from app_tracking where actionID in 
(
    select actionID from app_event_task where eventID in (
     select id from app_event where cId = 11 and categoryID = 3 and active = 1
      )
   )
```

How can I rewrite this in Linq so the database is only accessed once?

Comment: Are you using EF or linq-to-sql? On a side note, your ToArray and ToList is what causing query execution. Try to remove the two ToArrays and repeat.

Comment: I am using LinqPad to run my test queries. Then will take it into EF.

Comment: LinqPad is a sort of IDE. [EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696172%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) or [linq-to-sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are underlying data technologies. You can [choose which to use](http://www.linqpad.net/entityframework.aspx). Although queries for them are similar, there are subtleties in how they are executed, since the code base is completely different.